# iOS 7.1 and EA framework issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, mfi, ios7.1

We are using EA framework to communicate with our product. It was working perfect before iOS 7.0, but after testing on the iOS 7.1 it is not working properly.

After investigating, we found that sometimes EASession is not initialised properly so that we cannot read any data from device. Apple EADemo sample code has the same issue that we have faced as well.

Basically, problem happens in this code: [[EASession alloc] initWithAccessory:forProtocol:] 
After initialised EASession, it does randomly deny receive data from device.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Use EADemo example code from Apple (This is the simplest way to test EA framework).
2. Connect to device.
3. Select one of the protocols in the action sheet to receive data from device.
4. Go back to previous page.
5. Do 4 and 5 continuously until cannot receive data. (It is hard to say how many times, but it won't get data after some times).

Do any of you have same issue? It is a very serious problem as our customers will upgrade their device soon and it will affect our products.

Comment: Perhaps you should raise an incident with Apple Developer support?

Comment: @Paulw11 I have raised it to bug reporter last week, and today it turns out as duplicated. Apparently not only me suffer from this issue.  My guess is Apple introduce CarPlay in iOS 7.1 and it messed up previous stable bluetooth functions.